# How does this density function make sense?

Tags: probability, random-variables, convolution, density-function

> Let $X$ be an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $\beta>0$ and let $Y$ be a random variable with $P(Y=0)=1-p$ and $P(Y=1)=p$, where $0<p<1$. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Find the density of $Z=X+Y$.

In the answer teacher provided the following density function for $Z$:
$$
f_Z(z) = \begin{cases} 
\beta \cdot e^{-\beta \cdot z}(1-p) 
+ \beta \cdot e^{-\beta \cdot (z-1)}(p)
&\text{for } z \geq 1, \\
\beta \cdot e^{-\beta \cdot z}(1-p)
&\text{for } 0 < z < 1, \\
0 &\text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$

I don't understand why my teacher specified a different density function for $0<z<1$ and didn't use the same as the density for $z \geq 1$. Did he just make a mistake, or am I ignoring something?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

my calculations were:
$$f_Z(z)=\int f_X(z-y)dP^Y(y)=f_X(z-0)P(Y=0)+f_X(z-1)P(Y=1)$$
After writing this down it finally makes sense, i think it is because $f_X(z-1)$ which is density for exponential distribution is $0$ for $z<1$. thanks.

Comment: By law of total probability $P(Z \leq t) = P(Z \leq t \mid Y=0)(1-p) + P(Z \leq t \mid Y = 1)p = P(X\leq t)(1-p)+P(X \leq t-1)p$ with the caveat that $P(Z \leq t \mid Y = 1) = 0$ unless $t \geq 1.$ Now substitute and differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

If you observe $Z = z$ for some $0 < z < 1$, that means you could not have observed $Y = 1$, because $Z = X+Y < 1$ and $Y$ can only take on values $0$ or $1$.  So you automatically know that $Y = 0$ if $Z < 1$, hence $Z = X$ if $Z < 1$.  That is why the density has two cases.

On the other hand, if you observed $Z > 1$, then it could be because $X > 1$ and $Y = 0$, or it could be because $X > 0$ and $Y = 1$.

With this in mind, can you prove the teacher's answer?  How would you go about such a proof?

Comment: Addition question, i could calculate the $f_Z(z)$ for $z \geq 1$ but i thought it was for $z \geq 0$. How did you know that for which z it was defined?

Comment: @SelbyChing I'm sorry, but without seeing your own computations, there's no way for me to tell you at which steps your reasoning should be modified.  I can't see what you did, so I can't tell you where you need to make changes.

Comment: @heropup shouldn't you add that the exponential $X$ is positive when you say  "if you observe Z=z
 for some 0<z<1
, that means you could not have observed Y=1
, because Z=X+Y<1
 and Y
 can only take on values 0
 or 1" ?

Comment: @SelbyChing put your calculations in the original post via an edit. not here in the comments

Comment: thanks for the help, it makes sense, sorry for any breach of rules, im new here.